# "ifconfig" command not found and networking tools package information needed

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, ifconfig, centos7

I have 2 questions :

1) "ifconfig" command is not found in centos 7, i tried to find in /sbin, there also command is not available. Doesn't this essential tool not included in minimal installation ( I use minimal installation of centos.)

2) What related networking tools should in install to get it.

Thanks.

-Praneeth

Comment: No, [you should not be using this command or this package at all](http://serverfault.com/q/458628/126632).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ifconfig command is depricated in rhel 7 and replaced with ip command.If you still need that command please install

```
           yum install net-tools
```

For more info please refer to https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1119297

Comment: Most people don't need this package and there's usually no reason to ever install it.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton I dont think so,The reason RedHat or upstream is moving away from net-tools is net-tools used ioctl which is now a obselete kernel interface where as ip uses netlink which is a sucessor of ioctl http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink#History