# ifconfig interface down vs unplugging cable

Tags: linux-networking, ifconfig

What's the difference between `ifconfig eth0 down` and physically unplugging `eth0` cable? Do they mean the same thing to an application?

Edit:

I have an application that uses a specific interface let's say `eth0` and it crashes if I do `ifconfig eth0 down` and then back `ifconfig eth0 up`. Ideally the application should resume but it crashes. On the other hand, if I just unplug the `eth0` cable, the application is still running but there is no incoming data and if I plug the cable back again the data stream resumes. Also when I run `ifconfig` command (after unplugging the cable), the output of `ifconfig` still shows `eth0` as up. However `ifconfig eth0 down`removes the interface all together. One more thing, the routes are deleted as well incase of an `ifconfig eth0 down` but not in case of unplugging the cable. So I am guessing unplugging the cable physically is not the same as using the command `ifconfig eth0 down`. Correct me if I am wrong. Is there a way to simulate an ethernet cable being unplugged? Apart from adding a rule in `iptables` and dropping the traffic altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Do both to a test host and see what happens. As IP packets are higher level than either of them, your connectivity may be impacted. Unless your host has interface level redundancy.

---

Administratively down is a thing for interfaces, including Linux. From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/operstates.txt

> Linux distinguishes between administrative and operational state of an
>   interface. Administrative state is the result of "ip link set dev
>    up or down" and reflects whether the administrator wants to use
>   the device for traffic.
>
> However, an interface is not usable just because the admin enabled it
>   - ethernet requires to be plugged into the switch and, depending on a site's networking policy and configuration, an 802.1X authentication
>   to be performed before user data can be transferred. Operational state
>   shows the ability of an interface to transmit this user data.

Also, [stop using `ifconfig` on Linux](https://serverfault.com/q/458628/241174), it has been obsolete for almost two decades. As the documentation implies, `ip` command (iproute package) is what to use, it also has commands for the link level.