# apache how to know if a download/upload is being processed

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, networking, upload

We've a web server used for heavy uploads/downloads (may take minutes).

For doing maintenance disruption, we'd like to know if downloads/uploads are being processed at the current time.

The things we know are :

- `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log`
  but this one shows only information when the transaction is done
- `netstat -ntaupe | grep 443 | grep ESTABLISHED`
  but here we also have lines for every active session (the web service that is hosted offers a refresh feature that keeps a request open to the server up to the moment something interesting has changed).

How to know which open connexion has a bandwidth traffic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered `iftop` thanks to https://serverfault.com/a/248285/54845

With a basic setup in ~/.iftoprc :

```
dns-resolution: no
port-resolution: no
port-display: on
show-bars: yes
hide-source: no
hide-destination: no
use-bytes: yes
show-totals: yes
log-scale: yes
```

we can now see uploading / downloading traffic over https (port 443) in real time with the following command :

```
sudo iftop -f 'port 443'
```

More info can be read here : http://sickbits.net/iftop-finding-traffic-hogs/